# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oml.core.methods'

Tags: python, pip

using Python 3.6 in a virtual environment, this is the error I get:

```
>>> import oml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<PYTHONPATH>/oml/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from oml.core import *
  File "<PYTHONPATH>/oml/core/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .methods import connect
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oml.core.methods'
```

When checking the files at that  location:

```
(venv) [host]$ ls <PYTHONPATH>/
oml  oml-1.0.dist-info

(venv) [host]$ ls <PYTHONPATH>/oml
__init__.py  __pycache__  algo  automl  core  ds  embed  graphics  mlx  script

(venv) [host]$ ls <PYTHONPATH>/oml/core/
__init__.py                             float.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so    series.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
__pycache__                             frame.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so    string.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
boolean.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  methods.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  util.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
bytes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so    number.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so   vector.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
extref.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so   oaa.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Verifying the module with pip:

```
(venv) [host]$ pip list
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
...
oml               1.0
...
```

Answer (score -2):

It required Python3.8
After installing Python3.8, created a new virtual environment, installed dependencies, it worked.